# How to use `ps` to find a command line?

Tags: shell, command-line

I want to find top CPU usage pid, my script is here:

```
#!/bin/sh
ppid=`top -n 1 |sed -n 8p |awk '{print $1}'`
echo $ppid
ps aux|grep $ppid
```

but I get an error:

> `grep: Unmatched [ or [^`

Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Does `$ppid` contain `[`? it should be escaped since it is a special character.

Comment: i use "echo $ppid "cmd ,but only display some digits.

Comment: That works (for limited testing) for me.  If somehow `ppid` is getting set to something strange you should quote it everywhere (good standard practice anyway).  I.e. instead of `echo $ppid` say `echo "$ppid"` and in the `grep` also.

Comment: BTW, since you are just grepping for any line with that sequence of digits you'll see any line that has a pid for which ppid is a substring, along with any command that happens to have that number in its args (e.g. the grep command that the script is running), or in any other of the `ps aux` fields.  You might want to use say `awk` to compare to only the right part of the line.

Comment: i use ps aux|grep "$ppid" ,but it doesn't work.

Comment: See my answer below.  You would have needed the trickier `echo "$ppid"|cat -v` to actually see it.

Comment: Trying to parse output from commands built for human interpretation is at once the root cause of this bug, and very bad form. If you were asking instead how best to achieve your desired larger goal, you might get a best-practices answer that didn't use `top` (or maybe even `ps` -- if you're on an operating system that provides procfs, using that directly is often the best choice). For instance, the best way to get a command line from a PID on Linux is to read it as a NUL-delimited stream from `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`; what you get from `ps` or `top` doesn't have the quoting right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When all else fails, examine the input:

```
$ top -n 1 | awk 'NR==8 {print $1 ": " $2}' | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 28 42 1b 5b 6d 1b 5b  31 6d 31 38 37 31 35 3a  |.(B.[m.[1m18715:|
00000010  20 6a 6b 6c 6f 77 64 65  6e 0a                    | jklowden.|
0000001a
```

(I shortened your command.  Nearly every command that combines sed and awk can be better expressed with just awk. Then I added the second field, so we could see what's going on.)

The result is nondeterministic.  **top** will highlight changed lines; to do so, it emits an ANSI escape sequence.  If you capture one, you'll capture that sequence -- *esc*(B*esc*[m*esc*[1m --  which will look very weird indeed to **ps**.  The brackets in that sequence doubtless provoked your error message.

To fix that, your **top** probably has a *batch* mode.  In mine, `top -n 1 -b` does the trick.

> How to use `ps` to find a command line?

I'm afraid the best answer is RTFM.  **ps** is one of those commands with a lot of variation across systems.  My GNU version likes this:

```
$ ps -c -f -p $(top -n 1 -b | awk 'NR==8 {print $1}')
UID        PID  PPID CLS PRI STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      1300     1 TS   19 Jun30 ?        00:14:46 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/la
```

Other observations:

- Prefer `$()` to backticks
- While this kind of thing is fine for learning, look for solutions that don't involve parsing output from interactive utilities.  Under *account* in the manual, you'll find ways to capture much more information than just *command line of what happens to be on top at the moment*.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

OK!  I found it!  The problem is that top is including terminal control sequences in its output.  So you don't actually see it in the echo, but I noticed because it had put my terminal session into bold output and later I was trying to figure out how it happened and I traced it back to my testing for this question.  So, the [ that grep was complaining about is in the escape sequence that ppid gets set to.  I got a work around by adding `|tr -dc 0-9` after the awk, i.e.

```
ppid=`top -n 1 |sed -n 8p |awk '{print $1}'|tr -dc 0-9`
```

That will delete anything that's not a digit at the end.  But the `sed` needs to be adjusted, too, I think.  And, I suspect some of the digits may be from the escape sequence, so you need to come up with a cleaner way to excise the escape sequence.

But, in the final analysis this will be pretty useless.  The highest user of the CPU every time I ran that pipeline was the `top` process that's part of it.  In retrospect that's probably not surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Because your ppid retrieve null value
change your command to retrieve ppid value as below

```
top -n 1 | sed -n 8p | awk -F " " '{print$2}'
```

And other thing for happening this is **top process will end immediately**

This is in my ubuntu 14.04 os.

Comment: print $2 only get user,not pid

Comment: what is output of print$1? if it is pid then change in answer $1